# jQuery UI Slider adding step from other function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I have a basic jQuery UI Slider as below which has one control to increase the range

```
<button id='increase' type="button">+</button>

<script>
    var s = $("#slider-vertical").slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 200,
    value: 10,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
      $("#result").val(ui.value);
    }
});

$('#increase').click(function () {
  var step = 20;
  s.slider('value', s.slider('value') + s.slider("option", "step"));
});
</script>
```

What I would like to do is to keep the original `.slider()` function without `step` option (to have smooth scroll function) but add step to `increase` button click. I added the `var step = 20;` to the code but it is not adding the property to the slider. How can I fix this?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/5TTm4/1509/)

Comment: Can you post a http://jsfiddle.net of this?

Comment: Hi Andrew, here you are :http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/5TTm4/1509/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
$('#slider-vertical').val(step);
$('#slider-vertical').slider('refresh');
```

and be sure your code is in $(function() { });

```
do you use <input type="range" or <div> ?
```

also im not sure the var s is equal to the jquery element, try replace

```
var s = $("#slider-vertical").slider({
```

to

```
var s = $("#slider-vertical");
s.slider({
```

Comment: Hi Benito, thanks for reply but I think you misunderstood the issue! the slide is working on my side too. what I want to add STEP to the slider NOT in the initial method

Comment: There is just one big issue here :-)

Comment: Have you notice that the slider ended at 225, while the range is just 200!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49692/discussion-between-mona-coder-and-benoit)